# GitVersion is not caching version number

Tags: teamcity-9.0, gitversion

I am close to getting GiVersion to work on TeamCity. But GitVersion puts 5 minutes on my build time because it not caching the version number.

```
[WriteVersionInfoToBuildLog]   INFO [07/14/16 13:55:32:72] Cache file C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e21746ec702e5b5d\.git\gitversion_cache\3012A3203E0BBA59F13642534D34033F6E301B69.yml not found.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Version 3.6.0 has broken the cache rolled back to version 3.5.4